# How is the server-side value being assigned in this ASP.NET custom control?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am looking at somebody else's code and in it there is a user control:

```
<UserControl:Comments ID="Comments1" runat="server" ObjectID="4" ObjectRecordID='<%#((Alert)Container.DataItem).AlertId %>'></UserControl:Comments>
```

What I don't quite understand is how the value for ObjectRecordID gets assigned. I 
understand by looking at the code that AlerId is getting assigned to ObjectRecordID 
but how is ((Alert)Container.DataItem).AlertId grabbing its value?

Thanks.

Comment: by the way, the control is inside the ItemTemplate tags of a repeater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Container` refers to the parent control of the comment box, which would be a single "row" of the Repeater.

`Container.DataItem` is a single object from *the collection to which the Repeater is databound*.  Specifically, the object that is bound to the "row" being processed.

`(Alert)Container.DataItem` takes the DataItem and casts it as an `Alert` reference.

`.AlertId` grabs the `AlertId` property of the `Alert` object that resulted from the previous step, so that its value can be assigned to the `ObjectRecordID` property of the `Comments` control.

Answer (score 1):

the `<%# %>` element signals to ASP.NET that you are databinding the expression; Because of that, and the fact that it is contained within the ItemTemplate of a Data-bindable control, the property `Container.DataItem` is now available. `Container.DataItem` is an `Object` (which is why it is being cast to the `Alert` type) representing the current item in the list of data objects being bound to the control.